# Error when trying to install RVM on Linux Mint: No command RVM found

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, linux-mint

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.christopherirish.com/2010/08/25/how-to-install-rvm-on-ubuntu-10-04/

When I get to the part where he tells us to modify the .bashrc file, I get stuck. For one thing, the .bashrc file is nowhere to be found.

[image]

Second, I tried manually creating the file myself and put this as it's contents:

```
if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then

if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

fi
```

But when I try running the command `rvm notes` I get the following error:

> No command 'rvm' found, but there are 20 similar ones rvm: command not
>   found

What can I do to use RVM properly?

Comment: @taro: Isn't that what I'm doing. :/

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, I came here looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems to me the last time I assisted someone with an RVM install, Wayne changed it so that the install automatically added the proper lines to the .bashrc file. I am not that familiar with Linux Mint, but know that you can sometimes also see it as .bash_profile, or simply .profile. Another recommendation from me, and something that has caused me a lot of heartache when installing RVM is remembering to restart the terminal session after installing RVM. The easiest way of course is to simply close your terminal session and start a new one, or if you know your shell configuration profile, simple source ~/.bashrc in your open terminal.

Comment: +1: use the command `. ~/.bashrc` before trying to run `rvm`

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to follow the directions listed on https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ as they detail the exact set of steps needed for both Per-User and Multi-User installation types. They work for 1.6.x and up exactly as detailed, and were tested up to and including against 1.8.5 which is the current release.